# How can I run an Azure Cloud Shell script that takes longer than 20 minutes? Is there a way to prevent timeouts in Azure Cloud Shell?

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I'm trying to run a script which counts the size of my azure storage account. I'm doing this because I don't have access to the billing section.

The script is taken from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/scripts/storage-blobs-container-calculate-size-powershell)

My storage account is around ~2TB, but I want to find out the individual size of each container.

When I run the script in azure cloud shell, it times out after 20 minutes. Is there a way to keep it alive?

Comment: try  `export TMOUT=100000`

Comment: MS just does not want you to use it: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/598699-azure-cloud-shell/suggestions/19397707-increase-10-minute-inactive-timeout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is the [General limitation of Azure Cloud Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/limitations#system-state-and-persistence).

> The machine that provides your Cloud Shell session is temporary, and it is recycled after your session is inactive for **20** minutes.

If you want to improve the cloud shell, you could vote for this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/598699-azure-cloud-shell/suggestions/32558935-timeout-is-to-short-or-needs-to-be-configured-to).

Or if it is acceptable, you could install the [`Az`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-2.6.0) powershell module in local to run the script.

Comment: New link to Azure feedback as of 2022 https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/a0e2a002-0b25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0858

Answer (score 1):

I use tmux, and a new pane, I run a watch session, e.g. watch /home/myusername or watch ps, or watch something I am interested in. this works to a certain extent in the past, now, sometimes it does not, but still better than nothing and useful to have many shell session from one interface.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to run the script as backend job.

Answer (score 0):

Not an ideal solution but I get around this by adding a loop that prompts the user for a key.  I set a timer on my phone to ensure i hit a key in the console as needed.  It will stay running for hours if interacted with; this version will intended for watching a database import will spend 10 minutes drawing lots then 10 minutes for the user to hit a key and keep the session alive.

```
    while ($importStatus.Status -eq "InProgress")
    {
        $dotCounter = 0
        while( $dotCounter -lt 60 -and $importStatus.Status -eq "InProgress")
        {
            $importStatus = Get-AzSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus -OperationStatusLink $importRequest.OperationStatusLink
            [Console]::Write(".")
            Start-Sleep -s 10
        }
        if ($importStatus.Status -eq "InProgress")
        {
            Write-Host "Press a key to monitor the upgrade for another 10 minutes.";
            $null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown');        
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use nohup feature or try export TMOUT=100000

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).